# Webpack variables

Tags: javascript, webpack

I just started using webpack and i couldn't find any answers on the internet for my problem.

I have two scripts:

```js
var yolo = "lol";
console.log(yolo);
require("./module.js");
```

```js
console.log(yolo);
```

Why is the variable yolo not defined in the module.js ?
How can i solve this?

I want to write a complex html5 game with socket.io server.

Comment: Research CommonJS modules (you're going to want to do this anyway), and the reason should become apparent.

Comment: How can it be that I've never heard of CommonJS? It looks a bit complicated.

Answer (score 2):

In a nutshell, CommonJS modules work like this:

*module.js*

```
var yolo = "lol";
console.log(yolo);
module.exports = {
    yolo: yolo
};
```

*client.js*

```
var module = require("./module");
console.log(module.yolo);
```

Answer (score 0):

A great place to get started with webpack is MadeWithLove's [Webpack your bags](https://blog.madewithlove.be/post/webpack-your-bags/).

Once you get the hang of creating javascript components, it's a real easy transition into using Three js or some other engine for your game. Additionaly using babel you can begin to use es2016 and your modules can look more like this:

```
// yolo.js
export default class Yolo {
    constructor () {
        this.lifeMotto = 'yolo'
    }

    printMotto () {
        console.log(this.lifeMotto)
    }

}

// main.js
import Yolo from './yolo'

let motto = new Yolo()
motto.printMotto()
```

All in all Webpack is amazing and it will make developing your game a breeze.